# Is it possible to turn off the HUD in Borderlands 1?

Tags: borderlands

I'm playing *Borderlands: Game of the Year* edition (not the enhanced version), and I'm wondering if there's a way to completely turn off the HUD, so I can get better screenshots.

There doesn't seem to be a keybind or setting in-game to turn off the HUD however. Is there a way to turn the HUD off at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PC, **yes** it's possible to turn off the HUD.

You can open the settings file manually, and bind a key to the command `togglehud`, like so:

1. In your `Documents` folder, open `My Games/Borderlands/WillowGame/Config`
2. Right-click `WillowInput.ini`, and open it with notepad.
3. There should be a section of settings that start with `Bindings=`. At the top of that list, add `Bindings=(Name="F1",Command="togglehud")`. Change <kbd>F1</kbd> to whichever key you prefer.

Now, when you launch the game, you'll be able to press <kbd>F1</kbd> to toggle the HUD on/off.

**Note:**
Toggling off the HUD will also disable the display of in-game menus (Inventory, Bounty Boards, New U Stations etc). Note that the menu will still be open. You'll need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to back out of the menu and re-enable the HUD.